# Necessidade resistor de pull-down

Tags: c, c++, arduino

Estou usando  a função `attachInterrupt()` no *Arduino Uno* para reconhecer o fim de curso de um atuador. Normalmente se usa teste com `if()`, porém o ciclo do atuador é muito rápido e o reconhecimento por esse meio se torna complicado. Com isso optei por usar `attachInterrupt()`, porém não sei se no caso de interrupção devo usar resistor de pull-down na entrada. Alguém saberia me dizer se tem essa necessidade?

Atualmente o sistema está como na imagem.[image: Sistema atual]

Pedaço do código:

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin2), EndCourse2, FALLING);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin3), EndCourse3, FALLING);

void EndCourse2()
{
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    btnpressed2=0;
}
void EndCourse3()
{
    if(btnpressed2==0)
    {
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
    CounterAT2++;
    }
    btnpressed2=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha eu nao consigo comentar porque tenho que ter 50 pontos, e tambem isso nao e a resposta, mas te aconselho a postar sua duvida aqui que tem um pessoal mais direcionado: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/